# Bootstrap 2.3.2: drop-down submenu pull-left does not pull all the way left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a drop-down submenu to show up on the left side instead of the right side. I was reading through another answer and came across this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/szx4Y/51/

I would like this to happen in my dropdown-menu, except I would also like the carats on be on the left side as one would usually expect where it should be. I followed what they did and set up a "pull-left" class inside my `<li class="dropdown-submenu">` but my code ends up having the submenu showing up on top of the parent option. How do I get it to show up all the way on the left side? And is there a way to get those carats on the left side? It looks like it's built in to bootstrap. Thanks.

JSBIN:
http://jsbin.com/gavutekipa/2/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

the carrats shows on the right : becouse of the css ref:

```
.dropdown-submenu > a::after {
display: block;
content: " ";
float: right; => change it to left
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #CCC;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: -10px; => change it to margin-left
```

}

or the other option would be to to make it to .dropdown-submenu > a::before {
...
}
and experiment with paddings, floating and marigins.

for the submenu showing on left - it looks ok to me or dont understand the problem

Comment: Ahh thanks for your answer.. I'll test it out in a bit. my problem is that in the JSBin, you can see that the bottom two submenus do pop up on the left side, but unlike the first linked JSFiddle example, my submenus cover up the options underneath it (The actual word "Time" is covered). I would like it so that the submenus are completely to the left of the first 4 option menu so I can see everything written at one time.